# Unable to clear a mission to "buy something new in the stash"?

Tags: jetpack-joyride

I have a mission that tells me to "buy something new in [the stash](http://jetpackjoyride.wikia.com/wiki/The_Stash)" but when I buy something the mission isn't cleared. I have tried buying many different items such as clothes, head starts, gadgets, etc - but still the mission is not acknowledged as completed.

Any ideas why this is and how I can progress past this?

Comment: Are you buying something you have never purchased, before?

Comment: I used to buy one of those single use items and that always completed the mission for me. You don't have to buy a new permanent item like a jetpeck or something.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the only way to clear this mission was to purchase the "complete mission" item in "The Stash." It should be under "Utilities" at the very bottom.

Answer (score -2):

Very weird but you can first delete your history on device for playing that game. Or you might have a glitch and can contact for support to have help to.